# Display receiving email address (the one sent to) in message view or message list in Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, headers

not finding this answer on google. I am assuming this is difficult and/or requires CFG files or custom forms.

[image: screenshot of request]

I have a lot of aliases coming to my inbox, and **I need a way to view my *receiving* email address in Outlook so I know which email address received the email**. Currently I have to view the full message headers and scroll down to the **To:** line in the headers to find out which email address received the message.

Is there an easy/easier way to view which email address received the message?

Comment: Why not make separate inbox sub-folders and use inbox rules to sort the mail based on who it was sent to?

Comment: I don't want to be forced to monitor 10+ separate "inboxes". I know that is a possible solution, but far from ideal for me. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Forced to monitor them?  they'd be visible sub-folders with little numbers that show up when there's new mail to be read. :) anyhow, you assumption is correct, it's going to require using a CFG, if that even works at all.  Aside from 'googling', what have you actually tried already?  Did you look into using a custom CFG file yet?  If so, where did you get stuck? If not, I'd say start looking into that.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into custom CFG because it does seem there is no other way.